# I have implemented salesforce live agent and want to use this from external website. What things i need to share with external party

Tags: force.com-sites, liveagent, servicecloud

I have implemented salesforce live agent but i want to use this live chat in external sites not FORCE.COM sites. What components so i need to share with external party?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to share the deployment code and the button code, this is the auto generated code what Salesforce provides to you when you finish creating the configuration. This can be used in the external website to call live agent.

Comment: I have given the chat button code and deployment code to external party. but when they are clicking on chat now button it is asking user name and password. Do I need to do some setting in salesforce side? please help me out.

Comment: I have given the chat button code and deployment code to external party. but when they are clicking on chat now button it is asking user name and password. I have given VF page and class access to guest user profile too.I also given read,write access to account and case object also.

Comment: Hard to tell without. you posting a screenshot but if I had to guess, I would say that you set up a prechatform and that prechatform is not a public page, you need to make it public